# Overlaying LockScreen but when I click powerButton stack another activity

Tags: android

I'm overlaying LockScreenActivity.
But every time I then I click the power button, one more Ad(Admob activity) go to stack.

I just wanna one instance of that.

Every time Anyone can help with that?

OnCreate is normal.

```
<activity
        android:name="connect.adsslide.LockScreenActivity"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
 </activity>
```

Comment: Can you give more description about an exactly what is problem ?

Comment: problem edited   tks

Comment: Try to remove `android:noHistory` and `android:excludeFromRecents`.

Comment: and what launchMode?

Comment: As it is. `singleInstance`

Comment: The app create the activity just once.
So  the stack is :   MyActivity ->  ADMob Activity  ->  MyActivity

That's better than before, but still running once.
When I click at the button again,  the app call onRestart, that instanciate the screen again.  I just dont wanna that (maybe kill at onRestart)

Comment: Just start `AdmobActivity` without finishing `MainActivity`. And just complete `AdMobActivity` which automatically gives you a `MainActivity`.